Django DB Foreign Key on_delete=CASCADE combined with null=True
What happens if a Django model contains both - on_delete=CASCADE and null=True:
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    SomeInfo = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    SomeInfo2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ID_FK1 = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel1, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ID_FK2 = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel2, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

I see entries in the DB of MyModel with ID_FK2 being NULL which is not supposed to happen.

null=True will allow those fields to contain a null value. If there are values in FK1/2 which are tied to OtherModel1 (or OtherModel2) and you delete one of the foreign records, it will cascade the deletion of associated records in MyModel. If you don't want null, then set null=False but understand this will require both the FK1 and FK2 fields to be populated or it won't save the MyModel record.

Well it means that if you remove an OtherModel1, it removes the related MyModel, but you can still set the field (for example yourself) to NULL.

in that case, use SET_NULL vs CASCADE

Exactly what the documentation says. null=True means these values can be inserted or updated to be null values. The cascade deletion describes the behavior when associated objects are deleted.
